# SSMS: How to copy databases from SQL Server to Azure SQL Server?

Tags: database, azure, ssms

I am trying to migrate databases on SQL Server to Azure SQL Server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
I have tried copying by using Copy Database Wizard but when I entered both Source and Destination Server, an error message popped as shown below.

[Copy Database Wizard Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZyin.png)

I figured out that there is no such thing as SQL Server Agent in Azure SQL Server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean migrate?

Comment: Yes, I meant migrate. Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could export your database data into a json format and try it that way

Answer (score 0):

To migrate Databases to Microsoft Azure Sql Server you need the DMA(Data Migration Assistant). If you want to learn how you can do it check the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database).

There are to many step to follow but I think is easy to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your local SQL server database into Azure SQL server database. To do that you can use Microsoft data migration assistant (DMA). You can easily do that by reading my blog post [here](https://itserendib.wordpress.com/2018/10/05/migrate-sql-server-database-to-azure-sql-database-using-dma/).